# Move contacts between 2 accounts

Tags: contacts, google-contacts

On my Samsung Phone with Andorid 11 and OneUI Core 3.1
I have 2 google accounts. Lets call them ACC1 (private) and ACC2 (corporate).

By default when I add new contacts, phone add them to google ACC2.

Very often I change the destination account in time when I create new contact, but also very often forget to change them.

I do not see possibilty to change account after the creation process is done.

As I have them both (google accounts) configured on my Phone I want to ask:

How to easily move specific contact from google ACC2 to ACC1 ?

Comment: It started to get more compiled.
I have two contacts both with the same name. 1 stored in the phone. 2 saved in google contacts. How to check with the "Google contacts" application, ie without logging into the web, which contact is saved in the cloud and which on the device? I just want to select the correct contact on my phone and remove it from the device.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy multiple accounts you can use [Google Contacts web UI](https://contacts.google.com/) and their export/import function:

Step 1: Export existing Gmail contacts

- On your computer, go to Google Contacts
- At the left, click Export.
- Select which contacts to export.
- Select Google CSV.
- Click Export.
- At the top right, click your profile picture and then  Sign out.

Step 2: Import the file

- On your computer, go to Google Contacts, then sign in with your other Gmail account.
- At the left, click Import.
- Click Select File.
- Choose your file.
- Click Import.

https://support.google.com/contacts/answer/1069522/add-move-or-import-contacts-computer?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#zippy=%2Cfrom-a-gmail-account

Comment: Yes, I know this feature, but very often I want to move single specific contact, which I added few minutes before by mistake, and I do not want to especially login,export,delete,import via browser. It is too time consuming to do this several times a month. So I was wondering that maybe there is some utility program to transfer contacts between accounts, or just some option in the system that I don't see.